# How to ignore Mailitem in opend event, if it was opend for read

Tags: outlook, vsto

I registerd to the [`ItemEvents_10_Event.Open`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(MICROSOFT.OFFICE.INTEROP.OUTLOOK.ITEMEVENTS_10_EVENT.OPEN);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK%2cVERSION%3dV4.0%22);k(DevLang-CSHARP)&rd=true) event.

Now I'm only interrested in the items, if the user want to write a mail (new mail, respond) not when he opens an existing mail to read.

How can I differentiate between those two using the `Inspector` or the `MailItem`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `MailItem.Sent` property. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Outlook-VBA/articles/mailitem-sent-property-outlook?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396